# SQLite File validation

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Have a quick question. I am using a SQLite database file in my C# application. At the moment it is not password protected. But it will be in case it is needed as a solution for my question.

Question is is there is a way I can check is the SQLite file in associate with my application is a real SQLite file or not. I am doing a,

> File.Exists (filepath)

check at the moment which works fine. But it is possible that someone can create a file with my file extension so how can I verify that it is a valid Sqlite file ????

Thanks in advance !

Comment: By "valid" do you mean well-formed and readable, or data-not-tampered-with?

Comment: any user can create a file with my SQLite file name and extension but how my program can validate it is a SQLite file not file that user created or renamed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the first 16 bytes in the file:

> The well known 16-byte sequence that begins every SQLite database file is:
>
> 0x53 0x51 0x4c 0x69 0x74 0x65 0x20 0x66 0x6f 0x72 0x6d 0x61 0x74 0x20 0x33 0x00

(from http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)

That is, assuming the password protection doesn't mess those bytes up too.